# Using JavaScript Plugins with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, plugins

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap 3 Datepicker plugin (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) with Angular 4.0.

I've included the necessary JS and CSS (and a custom JS script calling the plugin) in my `angular-cli.json` file and the script loads great on the first page that I open but stops working as soon as I route to another component.

I figure that I need a way to call `$('.datetime-picker').datetimepicker()` every time I route to the new component. How would I do that?

Comment: wrap it with angular component? and call $('.datetime-picker').datetimepicker() that in class constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a different solution try using primeNg google it.